# How do I perform a clean JSON decoding with URL parameters and UITableview

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to create a function that parse my JSON according to the ID at the end of the URL. For example: (https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/produto?categoriaId=1). In this case, "categoriaId=1" will return me a "Games" category as a JSON filled with Games. It should changes depending on each category the user clicks on my UICollectionView categories. So, if the user clicks in "Movies" on my UICollectionView, I gotta change the url to id 2 (for example) https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/produto?categoriaId=2 then I'll get the JSON filled with Movies and so on. However, It's not working what I'm doing wrong?

**That's how I'm trying to get the category ID:**

```
func getCategoriaPorID(IdCategoria:Int, completion:@escaping ([CategoriaIDItems])->Void) {

    let url = URL(string: "https://alodjinha.herokuapp.com/produto?categoriaId=\(IdCategoria)")

    let session = URLSession.shared

    let request = URLRequest(url: url!)

    let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        guard let unwrappedData = data else { print("Error data"); return}

        do {

            let jsonTop10 = try JSONDecoder().decode(CategoriaIDItemsData.self, from: unwrappedData)

            completion(jsonTop10.data)



        }catch{
            print("Could no get API data")
        }
    }
    dataTask.resume()

}
```

**Models:**

```
import Foundation

//Categorias
struct Contents : Decodable {
    let data : [Content]
}
struct Content : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let descricao : String
    let urlImagem : String
}
//Banner
struct BannerData : Decodable {
    let data : [Banner]
}
struct Banner : Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let urlImagem : String
    let linkUrl : String
}
//Top10
struct Top10Data:Decodable {
    let data: [Top10]
}
struct Top10:Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let nome : String
    let urlImagem : String
    let descricao : String
    let precoDe : Int
}
struct CategoriaIDItemsData:Decodable {
    let data : [CategoriaIDItems]
}
struct CategoriaIDItems:Decodable {
    let id : Int
    let nome : String
    let urlImagem : String
    let descricao : String
    let precoDe : Int
}
```

**Well, after that I proceeded to the main file (ViewController) where contains all my tables, such as, UITableView and also UICollectionview (Where all the categories are located).**

```
    import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDelegate {

        @IBOutlet weak var tableViewTopSell: UITableView!
        @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
        @IBOutlet weak var collectionViewBanner: UICollectionView!

        var dataSource: [Content] = [Content]()
        var dataBanner: [Banner] = [Banner]()
        var dataTopSold: [Top10] = [Top10]()
        var dataCategoriaID: [CategoriaIDItems] = [CategoriaIDItems]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            //Delegate TableView
            self.tableViewTopSell.delegate = self
            //SetupNavBarCustom
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.CustomNavigationBar()
            let logo = UIImage(named: "tag.png")
            let imageView = UIImageView(image:logo)
            self.navigationItem.titleView = imageView
            //CallAPIData
            getTopSold { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataTopSold = data
                    self.tableViewTopSell.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getBanner { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dataBanner = data
                self.collectionViewBanner.reloadData()
                }
            }
            getAudiobooksAPI { (data) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataSource = data
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
        //CollectionView
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
                return  self.dataSource.count
            }else{
                return self.dataBanner.count
            }}
        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

            if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

            let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]

            cell.bookLabel.text = content.descricao
            cell.bookImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")

            return cell

            }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {

                let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCellBanner", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

                let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]

                cell.bannerImage.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")


                return cell
            }
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    var indexPathId: Int 
    if (collectionView == self.collectionView) {
        let content = self.dataSource[indexPath.item]
        indexPathId = content.id
    }else if (collectionView == self.collectionViewBanner) {
        let content = self.dataBanner[indexPath.item]
        indexPathId = content.id
    }

    getCategoriaPorID(IdCategoria: indexPathId) { (data) in
            self.dataCategoriaID = data
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueCategorias", sender:self.dataCategoriaID)

            print(self.dataCategoriaID)
    }
}



    //TableView
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataTopSold.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "topSoldCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        let content = self.dataTopSold[indexPath.row]
        cell.labelNomeTopSell.text = content.nome
        cell.imageViewTopSell.setImage(url: content.urlImagem, placeholder: "")
        cell.labelPrecoDe.text = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
        //Colocar strike em cima do Preco Antigo
        let oldPrice = "R$ \(content.precoDe)"
        let promotionString = oldPrice + ""
        let attributedStr = NSMutableAttributedString(string: promotionString)
        let crossAttr = [NSAttributedStringKey.strikethroughStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.styleSingle.rawValue]
        attributedStr.addAttributes(crossAttr, range: NSMakeRange(0, oldPrice.count))
        cell.labelPrecoDe.attributedText = attributedStr
        //
        cell.labelPrecoPor.text = "R$ 119.99"
        return cell
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueId", sender:self.dataTopSold[indexPath.row])

        }
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

            if segue.identifier == "segueId" {

                let des = segue.destination as? TelaDetalheProdutos

                //.item possui uma propriedade instanciada na TelaDetalheProdutos
                des?.item = (sender as? Top10)
                //Segue para CollectionView Categorias
            } else if segue.identifier == "segueCategorias" {

                let desc = segue.destination as? TelaCategorias

                desc?.item = (sender as? CategoriaIDItems)
            }
        }

    }
    //Cast UIImage Extension
    extension UIImageView{
        func setImage(url : String, placeholder: String, callback : (() -> Void)? = nil){
            self.image = UIImage(named: "no-photo")

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: NSURL(string: url)! as URL, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

                guard error == nil else{
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: { () -> Void in
                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    self.image = image

                    if let callback = callback{
                        callback()
                    }
                })

            }).resume()
        }
    }
```

**Screen that will receive the data:**

```
import UIKit

class TelaCategorias: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {



    //Class Instanciated
    var item:CategoriaIDItems?
    var nome = String()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        ????

    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return ???
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableIDCategorias", for: indexPath) as! TelaCategoriasCell

        ????

        return cell
    }
}
```

***App picture:***

[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4w7UQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QUESTION SOLVED SUCCESSFULLY.

**FIXED**